# R Merge multiple vectors alternatively

Tags: r, vector

I have 3 vectors

```
x<- 1:3
y<- 4:6
z<- 7:9
```

I want to do combine these three vectors into single vector `k` such that

```
k
[1] 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9
```

I did this

```
k<-c()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  l<-c(x[i],y[i],z[i])
  k<-c(k,l)
}
```

I want to avoid loops. Does anyone know how to do this without using a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `rbind` the `vector`s to a `matrix` and convert it to a `vector` with `c`

```
c(rbind(x,y,z))
#[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```